# Deleting <li> issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building a recipe saving application where I have a form that looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/LHPbh/.

As you can see, I have a set of form elements contained in an `<li>`. You can click Add Ingredient and have more li's added to the field.

My problem is:

1. The first li is the only one that deletes. If you click Add Ingredient, and then try and delete that one, nothing works?
2. Is there a way to not have the first li have a delete by it, but all subsequent li's have a delete link on the side? (Just because there should always be at least one ingredient?)

Comment: My fixed version http://jsfiddle.net/LHPbh/16/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `clone()`, it isn't duplicating the events.  You need to call `clone(true)` in order for it to do this, as explained in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Answer (score 2):

You did not put an event listener on the cloned elements. Also, you should not give the "delete"-link its own id, as those need to be unique.

To make the first ingredient have no delete button, just don't include one in your markup but only dynamically create and append them to the cloned elements:

```
var deleteButton = $("<a class='float-left'>Delete</a>").click(deleteThis);
$('ul#listadd > li:first')
  .clone()
  .attr('name', 'ingredient' + newNum)
  .append(deleteButton)
  .appendTo('ul#listadd');

function deleteThis() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li')
    li.fadeOut('slow', function() { li.remove(); });
}
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/LHPbh/21/)

Comment: This way you never can delete the first element, even if you have other elements.

Comment: @Sylvanus: That is exactly what was requested by the OP, read #2.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LHPbh/2/

```
$('.deleteThis').live("click", function () {
        var li = $(this).closest('li')
        li.fadeOut('slow', function() { li.remove(); });
    });
```

It is answer to the 1. point. The problem was, that the eventhandler binding did not happen in newly created elements, because this code runs only on the load of the page. This can be solved by using .live(). And an other problem was, that id-s must be unique. So instead id, here you can use class .deleteThis.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHPbh/19/

This has added answer to the 2. point:

```
if ($("#listadd li").length == 1) {
    return;
}
```

If the list only contains 1 li element the rest of the callback will not run.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items that are added to the DOM dynamically, thus jQuery can't access them :)
In this case you can use the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(e) {

    //code here

});
```

Secondly, you were loading a quite old version of jQuery.

Thirdly, you were trying to select an element with an ID that already existed, and ID's can only exist one time. I've changed it to a class in the updated example.

Lastly, you were defining the class of the link twice like this:

```
<a class='float-left' id="deletethis" href='#' class="deletethis">Delete</a>
```

That also gave a problem, so I changed it to correct markup like this:

```
<a class='float-left deletethis' href='#'>Delete</a>
```

Good luck :) I've updated your jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/q4pf6/